# Finding the different possible combinations

Tags: text-processing, files, python, perl, bioinformatics

File A has rows of genes:

> A,B,C,D,E
>   P,Q,R
>   G,D,V,K
>   L,Q,X,I,U,G and so on.

Taking each row at a time, how can one get the following type of output:

For the first row:

> A,B,C
>   B,C,D
>   C,D,E

For the second row:

> P,Q,R

For the third row:

> G,D,V
>   D,V,K

Essentially, what I would like is to find "triplets" of genes from each row. The first triplet will have the first three genes. The second triplet will have the second,third,fourth genes. The last triplet will end with the last gene in the row.
Achieving this manually will be a mammoth task. Since I have yet to master Linux, Perl or Python scripts to be able to write a script for this, help from this community will be appreciated!

Comment: Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413493/itertools-product-to-generate-all-possible-strings-of-size-3-python

Comment: So what is the output exactly? One monolithic file? One file per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
function wprint() {
    print w[1], w[2], w[3];
}

function wshift(e) {
    w[1] = w[2]; w[2] = w[3]; w[3] = e;
}

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

{
    wshift($1);
    wshift($2);
    wshift($3);
    wprint();

    for (i = 4; i <= NF; ++i) {
        wshift($i);
        wprint();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$ awk -f script data.in
A,B,C
B,C,D
C,D,E
P,Q,R
G,D,V
D,V,K
L,Q,X
Q,X,I
X,I,U
I,U,G
```

The `awk` script uses a three element moving window, `w`.  For each input row, it populates the three elements of the window with the three first fields and prints these as a comma-separated list (followed by newline). It then iterates over the remaining fields on the line, shifting them into the window and printing the window for each element.

If any line in the input data contains less than two fields, you will get things like

```
A,,
```

or

```
A,B,
```

in the output.

If you are certain that every input line has at least three fields (or if you want to disregard any line that doesn't), then you may shorten the `awk` script slightly:

```
function wprint() {
    print w[1], w[2], w[3];
}

function wshift(e) {
    w[1] = w[2]; w[2] = w[3]; w[3] = e;
}

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        wshift($i);
        if (i >= 3) {
            wprint();
        }
    }
}
```

A generalization of the first variation of the script with a variable window size:

```
function wprint(i) {
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%s%s", w[i], OFS);
    }
    print w[n]
}

function wshift(e,i) {
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        w[i] = w[i + 1];
    }
    w[n] = e;
}

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

{
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        wshift($i);
    }
    wprint();

    for (i = n + 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        wshift($i);
        wprint();
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
$ awk -v n=4 -f script data.in
A,B,C,D
B,C,D,E
P,Q,R,
G,D,V,K
L,Q,X,I
Q,X,I,U
X,I,U,G
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -F, -le 'BEGIN { $, = "," } while(@F >= 3) { print @F[0..2]; shift @F }' file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NF>=3 { for(i=1; i<=NF-2; i++) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2) }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl we can tackle it as:

```
perl -lne '/(?:([^,]+)(?=((?:,[^,]+){2}))(?{ print $1,$2 }))*$/' yourfile
perl -F, -lne '$,=","; print shift @F, @F[0..1] while @F >= 3' 
perl -F, -lne '$,=","; print splice @F, 0, 3, @F[1,2] while @F >= 3'
```

which can be written in an expanded manner as shown below:

```
perl -lne '
   m/
      (?:                       # set up a do-while loop
         ([^,]+)                # first field which shall be deleted after printing
         (?=((?:,[^,]+){2}))    # lookahead and remember the next 2 fields
         (?{ print $1,$2 })     # print the first field + next 2 fields
      )*                        # loop back for more
      $                         # till we hit the end of line
   /x;
' yourfile
```

---

And with sed we can do it with an assortment of it's commands:

```
sed -e '
   /,$/!s/$/,/     # add a dummy comma at the EOL

   s/,/\n&/3;ta    # while there still are 3 elements in the line jump to label "a"
   d               # else quit processing this line any further

   :a              # main action
   P               # print the leading portion, i.e., that which is left of the first newline in the pattern space
   s/\n//          # take away the marker

   s/,/\n/;tb      # get ready to delete the first field
   :b

   D               # delete the first field, and apply the sed code all over from the beginning to what remains in the pattern space
' yourfile
```

---

Dc can also do this :

```
sed -e 's/[^,]*/[&]/g;y/,/ /' gene_data.in |
dc -e '
[q]sq                            # macro for quitting
[SM z0<a]sa                      # macro to store stack -> register "M"
[LMd SS zlk>b c]sb               # macro to put register "M" -> register "S"
[LS zlk>c]sc                     # macro to put register "S" -> stack
[n44an dn44an rdn10anr z3!>d]sd  # macro to print 1st three stack elements
[zsk lax lbx lcx ldx c]se        # macro that initializes & calls all other macros
[?z3>q lex z0=?]s?               # while loop to read in file line by line and run macro "e" on each line
l?x                              # main()
'
```

### Results

```
A,B,C
B,C,D
C,D,E
D,E,F
E,F,G
P,Q,R
G,D,V
D,V,K
L,Q,X
Q,X,I
X,I,U
I,U,G
```